# In my Zend 3 project an error 404 occurrs

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm starting to learn Zend Framework and I can,t find why an 404 error occured
in my project.

Project was made with tutorial on Zend page.
I will be glad for any help.

My project:
https://github.com/Kriz83/zend3

Comment: did you defined any route that you're trying to see? which one?

Comment: did you mean routes in module.config.php?